# Make columns same height in Vuetify Grid System

Tags: vuetify.js, grid-system

I'm currently creating a grid-layout in Vuetify, but I got stuck. I'm making a card-layout containing images. Here is the example:

[image]

I've tried it with the following code, but then small cards on the right are not aligned due to the margins.

```
    <v-container>
      <v-row class="justify-center">
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }">
            <v-card
              to="/pools"
              :elevation="hover ? 12 : 2"
              :class="{ 'on-hover': hover , 'overwrite-hover' : $vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly}"
            >
              <v-img class="white--text" :src="images[0]">
                <v-card-title class="white--text align-end fill-height headline">My Pools</v-card-title>
                <template v-slot:placeholder>
                  <v-row class="fill-height" align="center" justify="center">
                    <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="grey lighten-5"></v-progress-circular>
                  </v-row>
                </template>
              </v-img>
            </v-card>
          </v-hover>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="2">
          <v-card class="ma-2" light height="50%"></v-card>
          <v-card class="ma-2" light height="50%"></v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row class="justify-center">
        <v-col cols="8">
          <v-card light height="120px"></v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
   </v-container>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion, or maybe a similar example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you have a screenshot or a fiddle for what you have with the current code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Luckily you only need to make minor adjustments to the smaller cards on the right. Make use of flex and let flex do its magic :) It's basically telling the cards to grow to the maximum height available without clipping. Then add some margin in between the cards with the helper classes `mb` and `mt`.

```
<v-col cols="2" class="d-flex" style="flex-direction:column">
  <v-card class="mb-1 flex-grow-1">
    Upper card
  </v-card>
  <v-card class="mt-1 flex-grow-1">
    Lower card
  </v-card>
</v-col>
```

Comment: Link seems to be broken

Comment: Oof sorry for the broken link. Codesandbox apparently deleted all my saved projects in there. Imma edit the answer to remove the link but it was basically OPs question copy-pasted with my adjustments